# Is Apple charging publishers of free applications?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5

Let’s start with this statement: “We have published couple of free applications on the App Store and everything goes fine”. Now when approaching one customer, he told us that he heard that even we publish a free application, Apple can charge you as publisher. Well, we said, we never heard about that and it is not true and it never happens to us - but he insisted on this – therefore the questions is: “Is it possible that Apple is charging publishers of free applications under some circumstances (except of the annual fee for developer.apple.com)? ”

Thanks

Regards,

STeN

Comment: I do not understand why you close such questions. Application development cycle is not only about coding and not every development question is starting with "How to program....?" I think questions related to the uploading applications on the App Store fits the category "_practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession_"... fro your FAQ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont know where your client did read it, but apart from the anual fee, there's no other tax or price.

Maybe your client is confused with the developer fee?

Comment: Might be... I am also confused by this - my colleagues as well, nothing is on Google - but you never know:)

Comment: If the free app contains in app purchases or subscriptions then apple will take their 30% cut from that, but if the app is simply plain free, then Apple won't charge anything except the annual fee - as Tonio says.

Comment: Hm... that might be probably what he meant:)